# how to sort string as number in datagridview in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sorting

I have string column with numbers in a datagridview.It is not bound, I would like to sort it number wise I used

```
colid.ValueType = typeof(int);
grid.Sort(colid, ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

but is sorts like string eg:

```
11
12
23
7
80
81
```

while the expected is

```
7
11
12
23
80
81
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can register on the `SortCompare` event, for example:

```
private void customSortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
{
    int a = int.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()), b = int.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString());

    // If the cell value is already an integer, just cast it instead of parsing

    e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);

    e.Handled = true;
}

...
yourGridview.SortCompare += customSortCompare;
...
```

I didn't check if that works, but you get the idea... ;)

Answer (score 14):

You can just convert to Int32 when you assign value to column

```
DataGridView.Cells["example"].Value= Convert.ToInt32(text);
```

And it will sort correctly

Comment: This solution works better! More easy and fast. One Little tiny correction, just make "t" Capital:

"Convert.ToInt32(text)"

Comment: It's exactly what should to do to separate string and integer sorting in it's correct way, thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if this was proper syntax. There is no such syntax as DataGridView.Cells["example"].....

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you sort string values. When you load column you must choose type of values in column like that:

dt.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(int));

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like:

```
class Sort : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        return -int.Parse((string)x).CompareTo(int.Parse((string)y)); //sort descending
        //return int.Parse((string)x).CompareTo(int.Parse((string)y)); //sort ascending
    }
}
```

and do

```
grid.Sort( new Sort() );
```

Comment: @Mikael IComparer should be System.Collections.IComparer ,further we get gridviewrows in x and y hence it cannot be parsed into int or string,so it doesnt work.

Comment: @Thunder, IComparer is Sysem.Collections.IComparer. I didn't include the using statements, and you're right about the input. But it could be easily changed to handle gridviewrows and pull out the value.

I should have tried this in a solution and not freehand.