# Datagridview Sorting Bug

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I have a listview of items and each item contains different illustration numbers in a datagridview. When I do an ascending / descending sort these are my results:

[image: Datagridview ascending sort] [image: Datagridview descending sort]

Keep in mind the datagridview is quite large so I cut it down a lot. In any case, it should actually be doing 1, 2, 101 (in ascending)...

Here's what I get when I select these values in my database, they get sorted perfectly:

[image: SQL ascending sort] [image: SQL descending sort]

Does anyone have some insight on why the datagridview is sorting a little weird?

Comment: does 2 retrieved form your query? I mean is it inside your dataset binding to the datagrid or not?

Comment: @apomene Yep all the data is correctly retrieved from my database, just not correctly sorted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort string as number in datagridview in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674670/how-to-sort-string-as-number-in-datagridview-in-winforms)

Comment: @Steve Thanks Steve, in short that's pretty much what I did. I just  converted my string to an integer before adding it to the datagridview and everything works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Someone before me posted something very helpful which was that my illustration number column was in a string format instead of a numeric format. I converted it to an integer upon populating the datagridview and voila! It works!

Comment: Happy to help, for some reason it was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Oliver Yeah I was wondering why it disappeared! Thanks a lot man.