# Strange behaviour in for loop with DataGridView

Tags: c#, for-loop, datagridview, stack-overflow

I have a `DataGridView` that gets all its data from an XML file and I'm trying to convert all the cell values of a specific column to `int`, here's the code I'm using for it.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < targetTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!targetTable[6, i].Value.Equals(null) && !targetTable[6, i].Value.Equals(""))
            {
                targetTable[6, i].Value = int.Parse(targetTable[6, i].Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                targetTable[6, i].Value = i + 1;
            }
        }
```

When I debug this `for` loop the index alternates only between 0 and 1 forever, which leads to a `StackOverFlowException`.

I can't figure out the reason why it's happening, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If TargetTable is a DataTable, add an Int Column to it and populate it with the string column values. then delete the string column and rename the new column. If you want to put your column at same column index, use the DataColumn.SetOrdinal() function.

Comment: @Graffito, I forgot to mention but `targetTable` is a `DataGridView`

Comment: Is the DataGridView Bounded to a DataTable (or any other Dataource) ? If not, you may use the same principle for a DGV. For column index, change the new column "DisplayIndex" property.

Comment: Yes, it is bound to a data source, an XML file.

Comment: What method or event is this code running in?  Since the grid is data bound, you probably should be doing this against the data source, and not the grid.

Answer (score 0):

ORINGINAL: 
I think I would be using a Foreach on the row instead of doing a for, it may help with figuring out what's behind the strange behavior.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in targetTable.Rows)
        {
            if (!row.Cells[6].Value.Equals(null) && !row.Cells[6].Value.Equals(""))
            {
                row.Cells[6].Value = int.Parse(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                row.Cells[6].Value = row.Index + 1;
            }
        }
```

EDIT: 
Given the new information: that you just want to sort the columns as int, perhaps adding a custom SortCompare event.

Link [how to sort string as number in datagridview in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674670/how-to-sort-string-as-number-in-datagridview-in-winforms)

Comment: I tried using your code but still got the same error, so debugged the code to see what's actually going on and I saw that when the index is 1 it goes back to the `foreach` line, then the index is 0 again, just like it happened with my code.

Comment: Can  you give an example of what your DataGridView looks like? How many Rows and what the values are. Perhaps you're looking at the wrong cell, or your XML data isn't being mapped to the DataGridView properly.

Comment: Basically my DataGridView shows test projects and their status in real time, so there are columns like Project, Time started, Status and ID, the latter being the one I'm trying to sort out.
The point I'm really trying to get to is to sort all the IDs as `int`, but the program sorts them as `string`, e.g.: 9, 80, 73, 7, 65, 534, 5, 40, 33, 20, 19

Comment: As the DataGridView is bounded to a DataSource, it is not possible to implement a custom sort on a column. As indicated by @LarsTech, you should update the datasource.

Comment: Wouldn't you still want to implement sort for the DataGridView to handle when a user click on the column header to sort?