# Sort DataGridView column values as DateTime

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, datagridview

I need to sort a DataGridView by a column with DateTime type values in descending order (most recent at the top), but the closest I got was ascending order. Here's my code:

```
        DataGridViewColumn timeStarted = ProjectsTable.Columns[2];
        timeStarted.Width = 170; // Time started
        timeStarted.ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
        timeStarted.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
```

PS.: I've already tried using `ProjectsTable.Sort(timeStarted, ListSortDirection.Descending);` but it didn't work, the column values got sorted as strings instead of DateTime.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674670/how-to-sort-string-as-number-in-datagridview-in-winforms

Comment: Where does your data come from? If it's binding, and your dates data isn't REALLY of DateTime type (e.g a string, retrieved from a DB), you will probably have to convert it to DateTime before binding it.

Comment: @matcheek I've also tried that one before, didn't work.. thanks a lot though

Comment: @Kilazur my data comes from an xml file, and this is the code I've used for the binding:
                        `DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        ds.ReadXml(projectsDir);
                        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                        {
                            ProjectsTable.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                            projectsSettings();
                        }`

Comment: You say you tried matcheek's suggestion, can we see it? You should be able to implement a custom comparison with it.

Comment: @Kilazur yes, for sure. Here's the implementation:

`private void customSortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()), b = DateTime.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString());
            e.SortResult = a.CompareTo(b);
            e.Handled = true;
        }`
 
Then  `ProjectsTable.SortCompare += customSortCompare;`

The result was the values being sorted properly as DateTime, but in ascending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87166/discussion-between-alan-uk-and-kilazur).