# Sorting DataGridView by a Column that has both numbers and strings

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

So i have this data grid view that i have to sort it descending by a column that has both numbers and string, what i want to do is to put numbers first in a descending order then strings after that (i don't really care about sorting strings, only to be after numbers)

That's my code that works well for numbers but gives me an Argument Exception if the column has any string in it

```
DataGridView5.Sort(DataGridView5.Columns("Column8"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

Edit:

suppose my column has the following values

- 6
- 19
- man
- 1
- 253
- blue

i need i need it to be sorted like

- 253
- 19
- 6
- 1
- blue
- man

Comment: The msdn docs on DataGridView.Sort seem to imply the exception has nothing to do with mixing int/string values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort string as number in datagridview in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674670/how-to-sort-string-as-number-in-datagridview-in-winforms)

Comment: @MethodMan no not a duplicate it is different i edited my question see it.

Comment: @Flashi The question is pretty close, since you should handle the SortCompare event, just change the logic to do type checking and put 'actual' strings last in comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems you first want to sort the numbers to the top and then also sort the numbers numerically in descending order.

First, you need to sort by whether it is numeric or not.  You can do this with the int.TryParse (or decimal).  For this, you will need a throwaway "out" variable.

So, if it can parse the field into an integer, you sort by the number 0.  Otherwise you sort by 1.  That will put the numbers at the top.

```
int parsedNum; 
Sort Descending >> int.TryParse(s, out parsedNum) ? 0 : 1;
```

To sort the numbers in order, you will need to sort numerically, of course.  You may be able to sort conditionally, but you may have to convert to a string that is padded.

```
Sort Descending >> int.TryParse(s, out parsedNum) ? s.ToString("000000") : s;
```

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge, but which language is that ?

Comment: Sorry.  I was thinking SQL.  Give me a second.

Comment: thanks and please if you can provide a code for the given code i would be grateful because i don't know how to do this with a datagridview column