# Sorting C#.net DataGridView columns as decimal

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have a WinForms application with a DataGridView column that is populated with prices at runtime, the prices are string data type.

When I sort this columns using:

```
dgvDealerPrices.Sort(colPrice, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

it sorts the prices like so:

£10,350
£11,294
£8,999
£9,050
£9,099
£9,099
£9,149
£9,199
£9,199.99
£9,200
£9,299
£9,457.31
£9,899
£9,994

Obviously because it is sorting strings. How can I have the prices sorted correctly? i.e as decimals but keeping the string formating shown. I have had a play about with the SortCompare property but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort string as number in datagridview in winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674670/how-to-sort-string-as-number-in-datagridview-in-winforms)

Comment: Do you use a button to sort?

Comment: @Berkay Programmatically after the DataGridView is populated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own comparer:

```
dgvDealerPrices.Sort(new PriceComparer());

class PriceComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var rowX = (DataGridViewRow)x;
        var rowY = (DataGridViewRow)y;
        var strX = (string)rowX.Cells["colPrice"].Value;
        var strY = (string)rowY.Cells["colPrice"].Value;
        return Decimal.Compare(Decimal.Parse(strX.Replace("£", "")), Decimal.Parse(strY.Replace("£", "")));
    }
}
```

Comment: You legend! Tweaked it a little bit and it works a treat!

Comment: I'm glad I helped @TomCarroll :)